# Connection between mathoverflow.net and math.stackexchange.com

Tags: support

Is there any connection between mathoverflow.net and math.stackexchange.com? I ask because they are formatted in a very similar way and I've seen mathoverflow.net linked to multiple times in math.stackexchange.com answers.

More to the point, do the communities on the sites overlap sufficiently that it would be highly annoying/useless to post the same question on both sites?

Comment: See http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/41/differences-between-mathoverflow-and-math-stackexchange

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MathOverflow.net is a StackExchange 1.0 site for research-level mathematics.

Math.stackexchange.com is a StackExchange 2.0 site intended to be a place where you can ask questions too basic for MathOverflow.

As such cross-posting usually makes little sense. However when you ask a question on math.stackexchange.com that turns out to be more advanced than you initially thought, people often recommend to move it to MO in the comments (in which case you should do so).